# Save ng-options selected state after form post

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, forms

In my Django Admin app I need to populate, with AnuglarJS, one html < select > that has been generated by one Django form.
When I submit the form (not with AngularJS) and the django form validation fail, I need to restore the previous selected object on my < select > input.

```
     <select ng-options="vehicle.fields.name for vehicle in vehicles track by vehicle.pk" ng-model="selected_vehicle" ng-init="selected_vehicle='{{ form.vehicle.value }}'" id="{{ form.vehicle.id_for_label }}" name="{{ form.vehicle.html_name }}">
     </select>
```

You can notice the 'ng-init="...."' directive.

My current vehicles array structure is a bit complicated (I need to use Django Rest Framework to generate it and not standard django serializer).

My question is: Is this a tight solution to use AngularJS with Django forms?? How can I recovery the previous selected status of my < select ... > after postback (when Django Form validation fails)?